# Lista de postagens populares com os comentários do facebook

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

Estou tentando fazer uma lista de 5 itens das postagens mais comentadas do meu blog, mas com os comentários do facebook.

Encontrei esse código no google, mas como podem ver, ele apenas captura os comentários feitos na própria plataforma do WP e não do facebook.

```
<?php
  $result = $wpdb
       ->get_results("SELECT comment_count, ID, post_title FROM $wpdb
       ->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , 10");
  foreach ($result as $topten) {
  $postid = $topten->ID;
  $title = $topten->post_title;
  $commentcount = $topten->comment_count;
  if ($commentcount != 0) {
  ?>
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($postid); ?>">< ?php echo $title ?></a>
</li>
<?php } } ?>
```

Eu substitui todo o conteúdo do arquivo "comments.php" do meu WP (tema twenty fifteen) por este aqui:

```
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=779264268806634&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
</div>
```

e para mostrar o número de comentários de cada post eu utilizo este:

```
<fb:comments-count href=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>></fb:comments-count>
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer a listagem, já busquei no google mas não encontrei nada.

Agradeço desde já.

### **MODIFICAÇÃO**

De acordo com a resposta de @Lollipop e algumas pesquisas no google, fiz as seguintes modificações:

Adicionei esta função no **functions.php**:

```
if (!function_exists('fb_comment_count')) {
     function fb_comment_count() {
        global $post;
        $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

        $query = "SELECT comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = '{$url}'";
        $responseText = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q='.$query);
        $responseJson = json_decode($responseText);

        $commentCount = $responseJson->data->comment_count;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'facebook_comments_count', $commentCount);

        return;
    }
}
```

e no arquivo onde eu quero que apareça a **listagem** eu coloquei:

```
  <ul>
    <?php
      $loopMostCommented = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&meta_key=facebook_comments_count&orderby=meta_value&order=DESC');
        while ($loopMostCommented->have_posts()) : $loopMostCommented->the_post();
    ?>
    <li>
      <a class="transition-2s" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php url() ?>" rel="bookmark"> 
        <span class="reclink"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </ul>
```

Infelizmente nada aparece dentro da tag "**< li >**". Alguém pode me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço muito!

Answer (score 1):

Guarde o número de comentários em `post meta-data` para que você seja capaz de usá-lo para fins de triagem mais tarde.

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

**Devemos apenas recuperar a contagem dos comentários:**

```
SELECT comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = 'POST_URL'
```

---

```
function fb_comment_count() {
  global $post;
  $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

  $query = "SELECT comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = '{$url}'";
  $responseText = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q='.$query);
  $responseJson = json_decode($responseText);

  $commenteCount = $responseJson->data->commentsbox_count;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, 'facebook_comments_count, $commenteCount);
  // ...
}
```

Uma vez que possui uma contagem, agora faça um loop:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=5&meta_key=facebook_comments_count&orderby=meta_value&order=DESC')
```

**fonte:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919791/wordpress-show-popular-posts-based-on-facebook-comments